# rand() doesn't give me random numbers

Tags: c, random, srand

I want to print 1000 random numbers saved in a array. Numbers have to be between 1 and 10000.

I put `srand(time(NULL))` in my `main` function and the array have to be filled with random numbers in my `init` function. The `ausgabe` function is for formatted output.

But `rand` fills my array with numbers all in row.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 1000

void init(int * ptr, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(ptr + i) = (rand() %10000+1);
    }
}

void ausgabe(int * ptr, int size){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        printf("%5i\t", * ptr + i);

        if ((i + 1) %10 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(){
    int zufall[ARR_SIZE];

    srand(time(NULL));

    init(zufall, ARR_SIZE);
    printf("\n\t\t\t---unsortierte Ausgabe---\n\n");
    ausgabe(zufall, ARR_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf("%5i\t", * (ptr + i));

Comment: @DanByström rather: `ptr[i]`.

Comment: Thank you it is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`* ptr + i` is `(*ptr)+i`, not `*(ptr+i)`. You need to be more careful with operator precedence. (And to learn to use your debugger: 30 seconds in your debugger would have clearly revealed that the problem was the printing, not the initialization.)

Comment: when i try it this way i get this error: " lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  (*ptr) + i = (rand() %10000+1);" i tried (*ptr)+i and ((*ptr)+i).

Comment: ok now it works. Thank you. Can you give me the tip how i can control the output?

Comment: As Sneftel pointed out `* ptr + i` is the same as `(*ptr)+i`, and so is `((*ptr)+i)`. It has to be `*(ptr+i)`.

Comment: @SefaSimsek The assignment in `init` was fine as `*(ptr+i)`. The mistake was in `ausgabe`: `* ptr + i` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Note you can also write `*(ptr + i)` as `ptr[i]`.

Comment: do i have some disadvantages when i use ptr[i] instead of *(ptr + i) or is it 100% the same?

Comment: @SefaSimsek : The advantage is you cannot get it wrong in the way you did as there are no operator precedent issues because there is only one operator (`[]`).  Since it is an array, why would you use pointer arithmetic in any case?  It is just an unnecessary obfuscation.